# How can I remove characters from this created tuple? (Python and appJar)

Tags: python, sql

I created a tuple from an SQL statement and am trying to print it now in a text box but get some of the items having these {} symbols. EDIT: Items that have multiple words like {The Matrix} get the characters whilst singular items like Inception have no extra characters.

This is an example of the results of an SQL statement:

> [('The Matrix',), ('Inception',), ('Happy Gilmore',), ('Big Daddy',),
>   ('Love Actually',), ('Airplane!',), ('Hot Fuzz',), ('Wonder',), ('Pulp
>   Fiction',)]

```
resultmovies = c.fetchall()

print(resultmovies)


counter = 0
for item in resultmovies:
    program.infoBox("Your Movie list", (resultmovies[counter]), parent = None) 
    counter += 1
```

Comment: You should post a MCVE in your questions, maybe read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I'm not sure where the `{}` would come from, but you would perhaps have a better time with `resultmovies = [item[0] for item in c.fetchall()]` and then `for item in resultmovies: program.infoBox("Your Movie list", item, parent = None)` or similar.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with appJar but I'm not sure that your current `for` loop would give you a list as implied by `"Your Movie list"`

Comment: That appears to be a list (square brackets) of tuples, what do you need, a list of strings, a tuple of strings, or just one long string?

Comment: Why the brackets around `(resultmovies[counter])`?  That does not create a tuple without an additional comma.

Comment: I cant post screenshots but the example results I get in the text boxes that pop up afterwards for example have some results just like Inception without any other characters whilst others have {The Matrix}. I therefore believe that if its a single word it wont have these extra characters.

Comment: what do you think `(resultmovies[counter])` should yield? what is the result if you substitute this piece of code for `item` or maybe `item[0]`?

Comment: Thank you!! That works and gets rid of the characters but now I get this error:  program.infoBox("Your Movie list", (item[0]), parent = None)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Found a fix using your method:  counterd = 0
    for item in resultmovies:
        if resultmovies[counterd] == None:
            break
        else:
            program.infoBox("Your Movie list", (item[0]), parent = None) 
            
        counterd += 1

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is in Python and so to use the rows you have to iterate over the tuples .
for example : 
    for list in dictionary:
       for tuple in list:
           tuple +=',' + tuple